# Sending ImageView as attachment in Email-android

Tags: android, email-attachments

I am learning android and working on an application to takes pictures and send them through email. I have got the picture in ImageView in the code below, but am not sure how to send this picture as an email attachment, without saving the picture to file on the device.

Ideally i would like to know if that is possible? If yes can you point me the correct direction on how to implement the same. Also(optionally) if the picture can be compressed.

```
public class EmailPic extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

       ImageButton ibEmail;
       Button bEmail;
       ImageView ivEmail;
       Intent intentEmail;
       Bitmap bmpEmail;
       final static int picData = 0;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pic_email);
            initializeVars();
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            bmpEmail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        }
        private void initializeVars() {
            ibEmail = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibTakePicEmail) ;
            ivEmail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPicEmail);
            bEmail  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendPicEmail);
            bEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
            ibEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ibTakePicEmail:
                intentEmail = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intentEmail,picData);
                break;

            case R.id.bSendPicEmail:

                String message = "email Body";                  
                String[] recipients = new String[]{"mymail.com"};
                Intent emailIntent  = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("application/image");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
                startActivity(emailIntent);
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle ext = data.getExtras();
                bmpEmail = (Bitmap)ext.get("data");
                //Log.d("StatusActivity","bmpEmail >>"+bmpEmail);
                ivEmail.setImageBitmap(bmpEmail);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.ic_launcher);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

**EDITED:**

Declare the File variable

```
         File pic;
```

In your `OnActivityResult()` apply changes as below:

```
Bundle ext = data.getExtras();
    bmpEmail = (Bitmap)ext.get("data");
    try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
             pic = new File(root, "pic.png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
            bmpEmail.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

And in your send email code add the line

```
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic));
```

Comment: well it send the attachment , but the attachment has no extension. I tried csutomising it to `Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.ic_launcher+".jpg");` , in which case it didn't send anything at all , though it showed the attachment was send.

Comment: ALso this sends only the "R.drawable.ic_launcher", rather than the pic I took with the camera app.

Comment: I am not understanding what are you trying to say?

Comment: You have asked to send the image from the drawable only. You should have specify that you want to send image from camera also.

Comment: If you want to send the image from camera you have to write the logic accordingly for the camera.

Comment: I know that is not good solution but @misguided so provide solution accordingly.

Comment: Sorry mate , I might not have made myself clear. ALl I want is to be able to send the pic , I took from camera  as an attachment in email , without saving the pic.

Comment: @misguided Its not possible to send image from camera without saving it. You think of yourself logically how will you send the image without saving after capturing ? One way is you save image temporarily and after sharing delete the image.

Comment: ` E/AndroidRuntime(12955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(12955): java.lang.NullPointerException: file
 E/AndroidRuntime(12955):  at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:441)
 E/AndroidRuntime(12955):  at com.example.hello.EmailPic.onClick(EmailPic.java:69)
 E/AndroidRuntime(12955):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)`

Comment: `root.canWrite()` returns `false`

Comment: adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in manifest file , resolved the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, You want to capture the image from the ImageView, compress it and then attach.
Basically the process is :

1. Get the Image from the ImageView.
2. Convert to Bitmap.
3. Save it.(You have to do it in any case, if you want to attach it)
4. Hopefully you can delete it afterwards.
5. Attach to email Intent.

First of all get the cached bitmap of the ImageView

```
Bitmap myBitmap = yourImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

This will return the cached bitmap from the ImageView.
Compress it and save

```
URI FILENAME;    //URI For the ImageView, we need earlier to send
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fos);
fos.close();
```

Create your Send Intent

```
            String message = "email Body";                  
            String[] recipients = new String[]{"mymail.com"};
            Intent emailIntent  = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("application/image");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FILENAME);     //this line is added to your code
            startActivity(emailIntent);
```

You can delete the image afterward if you need to.

Comment: If you have read question carefully, he don't want to convert the drawable image into file.

Comment: We know that its obvious to save file to an SDCARD before attaching it the email Intent.
We can delete it later on

Comment: And yes if he took the picture from the camera app. It WILL be saved Brother :)

Comment: Where is the file stored? When I take pic on the camera, it doesn't get stored in the album. SO i don't know the name or the location. Sorry , I am new to this.

Comment: When you take picture from the camera it automatically stores the picture into sdcard/DCIM/ location